# elementor error show different in admin than in visitor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i was working on my website using a theme from themeforest and it uses elementor to create the page, everything went normal in the admin area as it show on this image

[how it look in admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbWzO.png)

but when i open the website as a visitor it show me this

[how it look for visitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UboNu.png)

any idea what did i do wrong? i tried to redo the few steps i did before i notice the error and it didnt work, and then i lost track of whats going on.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer

i was using this code in the slide

```
<span style="font-size:24px;"><b>HEALTH TRACKER</span>
```

and after i removed the `<b>` tag it was fixed, if anyone can explain it that would be great.

Thanks in advance